# Any way to change the sound generated by BEL (beep) in the Windows console?

Tags: windows, audio, console, system-sounds, ascii

When BEL (ASCII 7) is sent to standard output in the Windows console, a beep sound is generated.  (BTW, the name was officially switch from `BELL` to `BEL` way back in 1965!)

Is there any way to change the sound that is produced?

Answers for any (or all) versions of Windows are appreciated.

---

*Related, but different question: [Is there any way to set the volume of the system beep in Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/970580/is-there-any-way-to-set-the-volume-of-the-system-beep-in-windows)*

Answer (score 1):

The system bell is not configurable.  It is a system call handled by the operating system to the [beep](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/utilapiset/nf-utilapiset-beep?redirectedfrom=MSDN) function and the parameters are pre-set.  It is designed to be a specific tone, so you know it is the OS alerting you.

If you want to use a different sound, you can generate one with [NirCMD](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html)'s beep functionality.

Comment: Very interesting.  Thank you.  For Win7 and later, is it the `Beep` function that is called or the `MessageBeep` (https://docs.microsoft.com/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-messagebeep) function?

Comment: As an aside, I love NirCMD, but I find its beep function generates significant clicking sound before the tone is output.